# Innosetup EndUpdateResource (5)

Tags: inno-setup

With innosetup I have this error EndUpdateResource (5) when compiling a simple .ico file.
5 = access denied

I have disabled antivirus : same issue, I ran innosetup as admin, same issue.

Looked at the file rights, nothing special.

How to overcome this ?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing special in the log, this is modal window with this message.

Comment: I did chkdsk, reboot the pc, and I can read the ico file with any editor, but Innosetup does not like.
the last line of the log is creating setup files, updating icons (SETUP.EXE)
my feeling could be that the setup file is large (500mb) and the antivirus try to scan it while innosetup tries to update the icon ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - have started using ISCC to compile several packages from a single script.  Was working great for weeks then suddenly stops.  I resolved this by changing the read only status on the OUTPUT FOLDER (uncheck).

I'd have to say Martin Prikryl's comment was 'spot on':

> The error is most likely caused by attempt to write the target setup
>   file, rather then reading the source icon file. So antivirus can be
>   the culprit. Though you wrote that you had disabled it. – Martin
>   Prikryl

Answer (score 0):

I did a small project, and I carefully inspected the anti virus software (Microsoft Security Essentials), and real time protection seems to be the culprit, because it worked out. So the previous comment was good. 
Now I will remove this folder from the real time protection from the anti virus.
This is really bad because it happenned suddenly.